# On the Fourier transform of $f(x)=\ln(x^2+a^2)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation

I would like to derive the Fourier transform of $f(x)=\ln(x^2+a^2)$, where $a\in \mathbb{R}^+$ by making use of the properties:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}[f'(x)]=(ik)\hat{f}(k)\\
\mathcal{F}[-ixf(x)]=\hat{f}'(k)
\end{equation}
For the Fourier transform I use the definition given by:

\begin{equation}
\hat{f}(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-ikx}dx, k \in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
Until now I found out that by taking the derivative of $f$ and finding the Fourier transform of $f'$ I can then use the relation $\mathcal{F}[f'(x)]=(ik)\hat{f}(k)$ and find $\hat{f}$. The derivative of $f$ would be:
\begin{equation}
f'(x)=\frac{2x}{x^2+a^2}
\end{equation}
and by considering $g(x)=1/(x^2+a^2)$, I then have:
\begin{equation}
f'(x)=2xg(x)
\end{equation}
Now I know that the Fourier transform of $g$ is given by:

\begin{equation}
\hat{g}(k)=\frac{1}{a}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-a|k|}, a \in \mathbb{R}, k\in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
Now I must find the Fourier transform of $xg(x)$ which would be given by the derivative of $\hat{g}$ right? But how can this possible since $\hat{g}$ has no derivative?

I think I am really close now but I need that extra tip.

Thank you!

Comment: $\hat{g}$ is differentiable everywhere except at $0$. It is however absolutely continuous, so the almost everywhere defined derivative is what you want.

Comment: @DanielFischer Are you sure that I can do that? Because I think that I am not supposed to differentiate in this particular case. Is everything else correct until the point I have reached?

Comment: I haven't carefully checked whether you made any mistakes so far, and at the moment, I'm not in the mood to do it. Looks okay so far, however. Differentiating $g$ to get the Fourier transform of $f'$ is legitimate here (don't forget that there are some constant factors to take care of). Your problem comes when you divide by $k$ to get the Fourier transform of $f$, because what you get then is not a tempered distribution. And that indicates that something is amiss.

Comment: @DanielFischer So, in the end I can claim that the Fourier transform of $f$ is everywhere defined except for $k=0$ and that would hold, right?

Comment: Ummm. $f$ is not the kind of function where you can use the integral definition of the Fourier transform. However, $f$ defines a tempered distribution, and as such it has a Fourier transform that again is a tempered distribution. Some tempered distributions are given by integration against reasonable functions, and for those you can have a notion of "almost everywhere defined". But the manipulations of pointwise (a.e.) defined functions seem to give something that is not a tempered distribution, so something is not quite right.

Comment: @DanielFischer You are right, I do know that $f$ defines a tempered distribution (even though I cannot prove it). And I also know that the Fourier transform of an $f \in \mathcal{S}$ has a Fourier transform that is also defined in the same space. But the Fourier transform here is (finally) given by:  \begin{equation}  \hat{f}(k)=-\sqrt{2\pi}\frac{e^{-|ak|}}{|k|}\end{equation} which I do not know if it is a "function" of the same space. Anyway, thank you for your assistance!

Comment: The problem is the $\frac{1}{\lvert k\rvert}$. That's a non-integrable singularity, and since there is no sign change, we can't even go and interpret it as a principal value integral.

Comment: Minor suggestion to the question (v2): Replace the condition $a\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a>0$ in two places.

Comment: @DanielFischer Hi Daniel.  I hope all is well.  If we use a regularized distribution, we can find a FT for $\log(x^2+a^2)$.  While the FT is not a "standard" tempered distribution, it is a distribution.  I've posted a solution using this approach.  As always, I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

If $\left| x \right|^{-1}$ is the distribution defined as
$$\left( \left| x \right|^{-1}, \phi \right) =
\int_{\left| x \right| < 1} \frac {\phi(x) - \phi(0)} {\left| x \right|} dx +
 \int_{\left| x \right| > 1} \frac {\phi(x)} {\left| x \right|} dx,$$
then
$${\mathcal F}\!\left[ \ln\left( x^2 +a^2 \right) \right] =
\frac 1 {\sqrt{2 \pi}}
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \ln\left( x^2 +a^2 \right) e^{-i k x} dx =
-\sqrt{2 \pi} \left( \frac { e^{-a \left| k \right|}} {\left| k \right|} +
 2 \gamma \delta(k) \right),$$
where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant. Probably the easiest way to prove it is to compute the inverse transform directly from the definition of $\left| x \right|^{-1}$.

Comment: Hi "Maxim."  Under the $\lambda_1$ distribution, the scale factor $-\sqrt{2\pi}2\gamma$ on $\delta(k)$ is unfortunately incorrect.  The scale factor should be instead $2\sqrt{2\pi}(\log(a)+\text{Ei}(-a))$.  As $a\to 0$, this approaches $-2\sqrt{2\pi}\gamma$.  I've posted a solution herein and provided a section to show that the Fourier Transform has as its inverse $\log(x^2+a^2)$.

Comment: There is an issue with this answer, but the issue is completely different. Namely, $e^{-a |k|}/|k|$ is a sloppy notation because I've only defined $|k|^{-1}$ and, in general, a distribution cannot be multiplied by $e^{-a |k|}$. A cleaner way to write the result is
$$\mathcal F[\ln(x^2 + a^2)] =
-\sqrt {2 \pi} \left( |k|^{-1} + 2 \gamma \delta(k) -
 \frac {1 - e^{-a |k|}} {|k|} \right),$$
where the last term is an ordinary function (or a regular distribution). This is unambiguous. The distribution in your answer is identical to this one.

Comment: Yes, the distribution in your comment and my answer(for $\nu =1$)  are identical.   And it's crystal clear.  Again, much appreciate your time.

Comment: Any $\nu > 0$ gives the same distribution $\mathcal F[\ln(x^2 + a^2)]$.

Comment: Yes that is true.  $C\nu$ and $\left(\cdots\right)_\nu$ depend on $\nu$ such that the sum of $C\nu(a) \delta(k)-\sqrt{2\pi}\left(\frac{e^{-|la|}}{|k|}\right)_\nu$ is independent of $\nu$.

Comment: What _is_ the defn of the distn $1/|x|$?

Comment: @paulgarrett If you mean the distribution $|x|^{-1}$ that I'm using, it's defined by the first formula in the answer (a tempered distribution is defined by its action on an arbitrary Schwartz function; it can be verified that the formula gives a linear continuous functional, so the definition is consistent). We have to specify how we define $|x|^{-1}$ because the ordinary function $1/|x|$ has many different regularizations (the FT of a distribution is, of course, unique).

Comment: @paulgarrett The difference between Max's solution and mine posted [herein](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341554/on-the-fourier-transform-of-fx-lnx2a2/4199768#4199768) (and one posted [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186803/fourier-transform-of-logx2a2/4212607#4212607)) is that I am using the distribution $\left(\frac{e^{-|ak|}}{|k|}\right)_\nu$ (as defined in my post) while Max is using $\left(\frac1{|k|}\right)_\nu+\frac{e^{-|ka|}-1}{|k|}$ with $\nu=1$.Note that the differences between our solutions result in different coefficients on the Dirac Delta contributions

Answer (score 1):

If $1/|x|$ means even and homog degree $-1$, the only such distn is $\delta$. Attempting to alter this fact by arbitrary truncations can indeed produce several different seeming answers. That’s not good.

I’d prefer to continue the approach in the question: up to the constant there, the desired Fourier transform is the derivative of $e^{-|ak|}$ in $k$. Without loss of generality, $a>0$. Then the deriv is $-sgn(x)ae^{-|ak|}-2a\delta$. Then mult by the ${1\over a}\sqrt{\pi/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

> **I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that develops the Fourier Transform directly and is distinct and complements the approach I adopted in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186803/fourier-transform-of-logx2a2/4212607#4212607).  To that end, we now proceed.**

---

Let $f(x)=\log(x^2+a^2)$ and let $F(k)$ denote its Fourier Transform.  Then, we write

$$F(k)=\mathscr{F}\{f\}(k)\tag 1$$

where $(1)$ is interpreted as a Tempered Distribution.  That is, for any $\phi \in \mathbb{S}$, we can write for any $\nu>0$

$$\begin{align}
\langle \mathscr{F}\{f\}, \phi\rangle &=\langle f, \mathscr{F}\{\phi\}\rangle\\\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \log(x^2+a^2)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(k)e^{-ikx}\,dk\,dx\\\\
&=\frac2{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty \log(x^2+a^2)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(k)\cos(kx)\,dk\,dx\\\\
&=\frac4{\sqrt{2\pi}}\phi(0)\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(\nu x)}{x}\,\log(x^2+a^2)\,dx\\\\
&+\frac2{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty \log(x^2+a^2) \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\phi(k)-\phi(0)\xi_{[-\nu,\nu]}(k))\cos(kx)\,dk\right)\,dx\\\\
&=C_\nu(a) \phi(0)\tag2\\\\
&+\frac2{\sqrt{2\pi}}\lim_{L\to \infty } \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\phi(k)-\phi(0)\xi_{[-\nu,\nu]}(k)}k\left(\log(L^2+a^2)\sin(kL)\\-\int_0^L \frac{2x\sin(kx)}{x^2+a^2}\,dx\right)\,dk\\\\
&=C_\nu(a) \phi(0)-\sqrt{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\phi(k)-\phi(0)\xi_{[-\nu,\nu]}(k)\right)\frac{e^{-|ka|}}{|k|}\,dk\tag3
\end{align}$$

where the constant $C_\nu(a)$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
C_\nu(a)&=-2\sqrt{2\pi} \log(\nu)+\frac4{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,\log(x^2+\nu^2a^2)\,dx\\\\
&=2\sqrt{2\pi} (\log(a)-\text{Ei}(-\nu a))
\end{align}$$

---

---

**NOTES:**

In arriving at $(2)$, used Fubini's theorem to justify interchanging integral $\int_0^L \,dx$ with the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \,dk$.

In arriving at $(3)$, we used integration by parts to show that the limit of the term involving $\log(L^2+a^2)$ is $0$ and we appealed the the Dominated Convergence Theorem to justify interchanging the limit with the integration over $k$ for the second term on the right-hand side of $(3)$.

For $\nu=1$ and $a\to 0$,  $C_1(a\to 0)=-2\sqrt{2\pi}\gamma$, which agrees with the results in the previously referenced answer (modulo the scale factor $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ here from the definition of the Fourier Transform).

---

---

From $(3)$, we deduce the Fourier Transform of $\psi$ in distribution

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000] {\mathscr{F}\{f\}(k)=C_\nu(a) \delta(k)-\sqrt{2\pi}\left(\frac{e^{-|ka|}}{|k|}\right)_\nu}\tag4$$

where the distribution $\left(\frac{e^{-|ka|}}{|k|}\right)_\nu$ is defined by its action on any $\phi\in \mathbb{S}$

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{e^{-|ka|}}{|k|}\right)_\nu\phi(k)\,dk=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\phi(k)-\phi(0)\xi_{[-\nu,\nu]}(k)\right)\frac{e^{-|ka|}}{|k|}\,dk$$

---

---

**SOLUTION VERIFICATION:**

In this section, we take the inverse Fourier Transform of the distribution in $(6)$ and show that it is indeed equal to $\log(x^2+a^2)$.  To begin, we write for any $\phi\in \mathbb{S}$

$$\begin{align}
\langle \mathscr{F}^{-1}\{F\},\phi\rangle&=\langle F,\mathscr{F}^{-1}\{\phi\}\rangle \\\\
&=C_\nu(a)\mathscr{F}^{-1}\{\phi\}(0)-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-|ka|}}{|k|}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\left(e^{ikx}-\xi_{[-\nu,\nu]}(k)\right)\,dx\,dk\\\\
&=C_\nu(a)\mathscr{F}^{-1}\{\phi\}(0)\\\\
&-2\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-ka}}{k}\left(\cos(kx)-\xi_{[-\nu,\nu]}(k)\right)\,dk\,dx\tag5
\end{align}$$

Using "Feynman's Trick," we find that the inner integral on the right-hand side of $(5)$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-ka}}{k}\left(\cos(kx)-\xi_{[-\nu,\nu]}(k)\right)\,dk&=\int_\infty^a \left(\frac{1-e^{-\nu a'}}{a'}-\frac{a'}{x^2+a'^2}\right)\,da'\\\\
&=\log(a)+\int_{\nu a}^\infty \frac{e^{-a' }}{a'}\,da'-\frac12\log(x^2+a^2))\\\\
&=-\frac12\log(x^2+a^2)+\log(a)+\text{Ei}(-\nu a)\tag6
\end{align}$$

Finally, substituting $(6)$ in $(5)$ yields the anticipated result that

$$\langle \mathscr{F}^{-1}\{F\},\phi\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\log(x^2+a^2)\,dx$$

from which we conclude that

$$f(x)=\mathscr{F}^{-1}\{F\}(x)=\log(x^2+a^2)$$

Comment: @bazinga Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.