# Fourier series of $\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: fourier-series

> What is the Fourier series expansion of $\frac{1}{x}$ ?

The best method I could come up with was shifting the function by 'k' (shifting the function to $\frac{1}{x - k}$), so that while calculating the coefficients you don't run into the discontinuity of 1/x.

Is there a different method to calculate the Fourier series of $\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: On what interval?

Comment: Interval (0,2$\pi$)

Comment: On $(0,2\pi)$  it doesn't make sense but on $(-\pi,\pi)$ it does, search about "principal value"

Comment: Let $h(y) = pv.(\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{e^{i xy}}{x}dx)$ then $h'(y) = \int_{-\pi}^\pi i e^{i xy}dx =2i \frac{\sin(\pi y)}{y}$ and since $h(0) = 0$ then $h(y) =2i \int_0^y \frac{\sin(\pi u)}{u} du$

Comment: @reuns how do you know you can differentiate like that

Comment: @mathworker21 for example because $pv.(\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{f(x)}{x}dx ) = \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}dx$ which can be taken as the definition

Comment: @reuns Are you sure such one is the derivative of $h(y)=h(y,x)$ with respect to $y$ even though the function is periodic in the x axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fourier series only exists for periodic functions which are integrable over a period. You can choose an interval and consider the periodic extension of $\frac{1}{x}$ over that interval, but if that interval contains $0$ (even as an endpoint), it will not be integrable.

---

At risk of cluttering what was a simple and to-the-point answer, I'd like to address some of the comments this answer has gotten over the years.

It's important to note that, when I say Fourier series, I mean the *full* Fourier series (not sine or cosine series), and *without* making use of the Cauchy principal value. For such a series, all the coefficients existing is a necessary condition for the series existing, and since $a_0 \propto \int_L f$, integrability of the function over the chosen period is a necessary condition for the series to exist.

This can be circumvented by using the above modifications. The Cauchy principal value allows odd functions with a singularity at $0$ to retain the property that integrals over a symmetric intervals vanish, so all the $a_n$ coefficients vanish as a result. The sine series, on the other hand, just assumes from the outset that the $a_n$ vanish, with the trade-off of being a series for the odd-periodic extension of $f$.

(Despite the fact that a sine series *is* a Fourier series, I maintain the distinction in this case because it does not arise from the standard coefficient-based definition of Fourier series without invoking the CPV. You are welcome to disagree, as this is purely a semantic distinction.)

As for square-integrability, that is a *sufficient* condition, but not necessary for the convergence of a Fourier series, unless you limit "convergence" to mean "convergence in the $L^2$ norm". Different types of convergence have different conditions, and square-integrability is not necessary for all of them; for example, one can construct a non-square-integrable function which has a Fourier series that is pointwise convergent almost everywhere.

Comment: I would not make such a  statement.  Absolute integrability of $f$ and further conditions of regularity such as local bounded variation guarantees convergence of the Fourier series at a point.  But the Fourier sine series of $f(x) = 1/x$ on $[0,\pi]$ exists.  Note that $b_n = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin nx}{x} \, dx = \frac{2}{\pi} Si(n\pi)$ exists.

Comment: Yeah as @RRL points out we would better try to give an answer before just saying there is no such an answer. Take a look to "Fourier transform of 1/x"  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1522986/622884 Never loose your hope on making sense of what is hard to think, of making the impossible possible!

Comment: Actually, integrability is *not* the criterion, but *square* integrability, if you want to stick to the formal definition of Fourier series. By construction, (trigonometric) Fourier series can be used to represent any function in $L^2(I)$ (which does not contain $1/x$).

Answer (score 0):

Let $\hat{f}$ be the Fourier transform of some function $f$.

Consider the image of the integer numbers under this Fourier transform
$$\{\hat{f}(n) | \ n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
Observe that the inverse Fourier series of this set,
$$\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \hat{f}(n) e^{i n}, $$
equals (a.e) some periodic function. If you calculate the Fourier Transform of $1/x$, as it is done [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8itztttxPE) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3128198/622884), you get the Fourier series coefficients $$c_n = \hat{f}(n).$$
In this case, if the domain of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $[-\pi, \pi)$ then  $$c_n = −\frac{i}{2}sgn(n).$$

The same way it must be possible to make the same analysis for the Fourier Series.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that $f(x)=1/x$ is not locally integrable at $0$, so there is a problem.

As @reuns points out, once choice is to *interpret* "$1/x$" as being the Cauchy principal value integral $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\epsilon\le|x|\le\pi}{e^{2\pi inx}\,dx\over x}$. A similar "principal value integral" can be arranged on $[0,2\pi]$, instead, if desired.

But the non-local-integrability cannot be evaded. The "principal value integral" is not a literal integral, since the literal (improper) integral would require that the limits below $0$ and above $0$ be independent... which is not possible.

So, truly, one is probably asking about the Fourier series of a *distribution*, given by the principal-value-integral (as in @reuns' answer).