# Fourier transform of function $1/ \vert x \vert$

Tags: fourier-transform

What is the Fourier transform of function $$f(x) = \frac{1}{\vert x \vert}?$$
This is not a homework. I would also appreciate help for calculating it myself.

Comment: You can use the radial and homogeneity properties of the Fourier Transform i.e. the FT of a radial function will be radial and the FT of a homogeneous function with deg $s$ is also a homogeneous function of deg $-n-s$ where $n$ is the dimension of the space.

Comment: The function is in neither $L^1$ nor $L^2,$ so what do you mean, exactly>

Comment: Yes but is it a distribution? Fourier transform of $1/x$ is defined. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships,_one-dimensional.

Comment: Is it in one dimension or in several?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522986/what-is-the-fourier-transform-of-1-x

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723136/the-fourier-transform-of-1-p3

Answer (score 0):

**Solution in one dimension**

We first note that $x \dfrac{1}{|x|} = \operatorname{sign}(x)$. Taking the Fourier transform of both sides clearly gives
$$
\mathcal{F}\{x \dfrac{1}{|x|}\} = \mathcal{F}\{\operatorname{sign}(x)\}.
$$
But the left hand side can now be rewritten as $i\frac{d}{d\xi}\mathcal{F}\{\dfrac{1}{|x|}\}$ and the right hand side can be calculated by
$$
i\xi \, \mathcal{F}\{\operatorname{sign}(x)\}
= \mathcal{F}\{\frac{d}{dx}\operatorname{sign}(x)\}
= \mathcal{F}\{2\delta(x)\}
= 2,
$$
since $\mathcal{F}\{\delta(x)\} = 1.$ Therefore
$$
\mathcal{F}\{\operatorname{sign}(x)\} = \operatorname{pv}\frac{2}{i\xi} + A\delta(\xi)
$$
for some constant $A.$ But $\operatorname{sign}(x)$ is an odd function and so shall be the Fourier transform; therefore $A=0.$

Thus,
$$
i\frac{d}{d\xi}\mathcal{F}\{\dfrac{1}{|x|}\} = \operatorname{pv}\frac{2}{i\xi}
$$
so
$$
\mathcal{F}\{\dfrac{1}{|x|}\}
= -\ln|\xi| + B
$$
for some constant $B.$

Determining the constant can be done, but is not trivial.